# How to make 2 level scrolling tab in CSS like this in HTML 5

Tags: html, css

I need to make tabs like this which is having horizontal scroll and I'm using HTML 5 `figure` and `figure` caption

**HTML example**

```
<div class="footernav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <figure> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/fashion/" class="fluid">
        <figcaption>
                <h3>Product Name</h3>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footernav {white-space;no-wrap; padding-top: 0.2%; border-top: 1px solid white; overflow: auto; white-space:nowrap; padding-bottom: 1.9%;}
.footernav a { text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; padding-right: 1.5%; padding-left: 1.5%; text-align: center; margin-top: 1.1em; overflow:hidden; }
.footernav figure:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
.footernav img { min-width: 118px; max-width: 118px; padding:3px;  }
figure{margin:0}
.footernav a:hover,
.footernav a.selected { border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px; background:red}
.footernav h3 { color: #000; font-weight: 700; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.3em; font-size: 1.1em; text-transform: uppercase; margin-top:0.5em }
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/XnAsL/1/ **(Link updated)**

Now how to 2nd level and make it like the below picture?

**Both level should scroll.**

[image]

Comment: Confused.... do you want two rows of product or when i click one product in the first row, next row should pop, which also should be scrolling...?

Comment: @Starx - Both. when page will be open then any one will be default selected. But user can select any other items from first row. 2nd row sub-items are related to the main selected item of 1st row. itmes in 2nd row has link to their product pages. 1st row items will only open sub-itmes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a simplest logic i could think of.

Check the update of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XnAsL/2/).

I just copied your div, gave them a common class to denote as sub item. Then used a rel attribute on the original link to show those boxes.

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(".subtabs").hide();
    $("#"+rel).show();
});
```

**Update:**

Since you want a CSS solution, in order to denote sub items the best(or only) way is too nest them inside. But your current markup pattern, will not allow it. as an inline element will contain a block element. Although this will be valid under HTML5 (which of course is still in experimental phase), does not render as expected (in fact the div will pop right out of the  tag). So you have to change the markup style to something fit.

As per our discussion, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnAsL/8/) does what is needed.

**Update II**

Since you said, scripting will be done by someone else. A simple snippet will get the job the job done. A particular row will be selected and will remained selected when the user clicks it... [You can check the fiddle of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/XnAsL/9/)

```
$(".footernav > li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

<sub>P.S.
Second row positioning is not working properly inside the fiddle's box. So you might have test in a seperate page.</sub>

Comment: +1 Thanks but when I selct 1st row itesm, it doesn't select items in 2nd row

Comment: SO you want all the items to be selected (but how, do you want to denote the selection? may be throught a checkbox, or an attribute). Please explain a bit ... :)

Comment: I want to change and select tab something like this but with my mark-up http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/Rx3FQ/

Comment: one more example http://jsfiddle.net/xHY9Y/2/ but in my case I want to use my mark-up pattern and both rows should scroll horizontally

Comment: @JitendraVyas, By seeing your examples, i think you got what you needed. Let me tell you, what i understodd. only last thing that is remaining is the items in the first row also should also scroll, as it might contain multiple items. RIGHT?

Comment: I mean I want to with <a>, `figure` and `figcaption`. Which I'm using currently

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6289/discussion-between-starx-and-jitendra-vyas)